# Href on image not work properly

Tags: asp.net, href

I got silly problem. I use on image href statement for url redirection.
SO i got this menu tab

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Test/TestODS.aspx" Text="Katalog" Value="Katalog"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UploadNewOne.aspx" Text="Upload" Value="Upload"/>
```

and my image:

```
 <a href='~/Default.aspx'>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="70px" 
                ImageUrl="~/Images/i-sova.jpg"/>
            </a>
```

So problem is that when i click on Katalog , app redirect me on sub-domain Test/TestODS.aspx. From this page when i click on image im redirect on wrong url which doesnt exist >> /Test/Default.aspx
So anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a **tilde**, you will need to add `runat=server` to the `<a>` tag

```
<a href='~/Default.aspx' runat="server">
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you so much i tried add tilde but without runat it wasnt work.

Comment: @Alexander_Dracka, can you mark it as the answer for others who have the same issue.

Comment: sure i had to wait:) Thank you